# Construction of finite fields

Tags: linear-algebra, finite-fields, irreducible-polynomials

[This is the correct question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xm4D4.png)

[This is my answer for 1.1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YcMpp.png)

[This is my answer for 1.2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/49Qm2.png)

I have renewed this question correctly and I have done 1.1.
But in 1.2，I don’t know whether it is correct to fill this muliplication table.
Many thanks!

Comment: Well, $x^2+2x+1 = (x+1)^2$ is *not* irreducible, so that's an issue.

Comment: @DustanLevenstein Thanks - I thought I was missing something...

Comment: P(x) is reducible but the question needs me to prove it is irreducible. I am confused.

Comment: Well, so the question is wrong. Since it's not irreducible you shouldn't try to show it's irreducible. If this is homework the thing to do is explain why what you're asked to prove is false. For extra credit find and solve a corrected version of the question - here maybe come up with an irreducible quadratic, then do the rest of the problem with your polynomial in place of the given one.

Comment: ... did you actually evaluate $2^2+2\cdot 2 + 1$ mod $3$ when you wrote your answer?

Comment: yes,it actually equals to 0. But in that way I may not prove it is irreducible.

Comment: You can't just prove something that's false. That's not how math works!

Comment: So you knew what you wrote was wrong but wrote it anyway because that was the only way you could show $p$ was irreducible? Don't do that.

Comment: Thank you! I will explain this to my teacher.

Comment: It's probably just a typo and you should ask them for a correction. Try not to blindly follow what's asked of you - sometimes professors make mistakes!

Comment: Hi，I have renewed this question.I am a little confused about this muliplication table for 1.2.

Comment: Your table is good!

Comment: Thank you for your kindness help！

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $p=x^2+x+2$ (I assume there is a typo on your sheet). Let $X$ be the image of $x$ in $\mathbb F_3[x]/(p).$

**1.)** Show that $p$ has no roots (this suffices since p has degree 2). Since $p$ is irreducible it follows that $(p)$ is a maximal ideal (use that $F[x]$ is a PID for and field $F$).

**2.)** This is only some calculation. You can take some primitive element (in this case you can take $X$, see later), then just take powers of it and mod out $p$. So $X^2=1+2X$, $X^3=2+2X$ etc.

**3.)** Here you can factor the cyclotomic polynomial in $\mathbb F_3[x]$ and get $x^4+1=(2 + x + x^2) (2 + 2 x + x^2)$. So the roots of these two polynomials are the primitive elements of your fieldextension. From this you know that our $X$ is a primitve element. The generators of $C_8$ are $1,3,5,7$, so you know the primitve elements are $X^1,X^3,X^5,X^7$.

Comment: Hi,there.I have renewed this question.Can you take a look for what I have done for this question?I am a little confused about this muliplication table.Many thanks!

Comment: Where are you confused? And you didn't show that it is a field.

Comment: I showed it in 1.1.Anyway,thank you for answering! I have finished this question.